# monitoring bean using EJB3

Tags: ejb-3.0, jms

I'm working on a system where we write all of our events to a Topic where they get picked up by a TraceLoggingSubscriberMDB, PrivacyLoggingSubscriberMDB and I'm hoping to add a MonitoringSubscriberMDB. What the monitoring subscriber would do is to make sure a message coming into the system completed it's workflow.

For example a single inbound message would generate JMS messages, "Event 1", "Event 2", "Event N" that each get published to the event Topic. I need a way to see if something gets hung up on "Event 2" and send an email. I'm not sure how to approach this since everything is stateless. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using an [Interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html) over the MDB processing the events. It could check for some exception and raise some alert.